# Алгоритм поиска количества "счастливых билетов": добавить скорости?

Tags: c, оптимизация, алгоритм

В общем-то ничего серьёзного, развлекательная задача про поиск количества "счастливых билетов". [Описание алгоритма](http://www.ega-math.narod.ru/Quant/Tickets.htm#A2). %Subj% :-)

[image: рекуррентная формула]

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long long
N( size_t n, size_t k )
{
    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    size_t m = 0;

    if( !n ) return 0;
    if( n == 1 ) return (k <= 9);

    for( ; m <= 9; m++ )
    {
        if( k < 9 )
        {
            if( m <= k ) sum += N( n-1, k-m );
        }
        else
        {
            sum += N( n-1, k-m );
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

static unsigned long long
l_t( size_t digits )
{
    unsigned long long tickets = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    for( ; i <= (digits*9); i++ )
    {
        unsigned long long n = N( digits, i );
        tickets += n*n;
    }
    return tickets;
}

int main()
{
    printf
    (
        "1: %llu\n2: %llu\n3: %llu\n4: %llu\n5: %llu\n6: %llu\n7: %llu\n8: %llu\n", 
        l_t(1),l_t(2),l_t(3),l_t(4),l_t(5),l_t(6),l_t(7),l_t(8)
    );
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Вы много раз перевычисляете `N_i(k)`. Попробуйте пробежаться по i и на каждом шаге запомнить все `N_i(k)` в массиве.

Comment: Если обсчитывать сразу несколько - может быть, да. Но количество вызовов N() для digits=7 и 8 отличается на порядок (3 666 660 и 41 666 659)...

Comment: @avp: (там комментарии закончились) Спасибо! Польщён!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то наподобие этого должно прокатить:

```
int** N = malloc(9 * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    int length = i * 9 + 1;
    N[i] = malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    if (i == 1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            N[i][j] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned long long runningsum = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for ( ; k <= length / 2; k++)
        {
            runningsum += N[i-1][k];
            if (k >= 10)
               runningsum -= N[i-1][k-10];
            N[i][k] = runningsum;
        }
        for ( ; k < length; k++)
        {
            N[i][k] = N[i][length - 1 - k];
        }
    }
}
```

Работает вроде правильно: http://ideone.com/yHXArN (сравнивал с таблицей в статье)

Вот весь код: http://ideone.com/FVNJdH

Comment: Было неправильно, скорректировал

Comment: @VladD, а где у Вас начальные значения в N заносятся?

И обратите внимание, метка вопроса Си, ане С++.

Comment: @avp: вы правы, начальных значений не было, добавил. Сейчас переведу на чистый C...

Comment: @avp: перевёл.

Comment: О! Начальный вариант:


    1: 10
    2: 670
    3: 55252
    4: 4816030
    5: 432457640
    6: 39581170420
    7: 3671331273480
    8: 343900019857310

    real    0m8.597s
    user    0m8.589s
    sys     0m0.008s


Ваш:


    1: 10
    2: 670
    3: 55252
    4: 4816030
    5: 432457640
    6: 39581170420
    7: 3671331273480
    8: 343900019857310

    real    0m0.007s
    user    0m0.004s
    sys     0m0.004s


Шикарно :)

Comment: @klopp: спасибо :)

Comment: @VladD, мои поздравления! 

Просто классический пример, иллюстрирующий высказывание то ли Дейксты, то ли Вирта о том, что 

(цитирую по памяти) *"истинная эффективность программ зависит в первую очередь от алгоритмов и адекватных структур данных"*.

--

Скачал и прогнал у себя, явно быстрее 0.01 сек процессорного времени

    real 0m0.048s
    user 0m0.000s
    sys  0m0.028s

Answer (score 2):

Тривиальная замена `for (...) { ... }` в `N()` на

```
// optimize
if (k < 9) {
  for (; m <= k; m++)
    sum += N(n-1, k-m);
} else {
  for (; m < 10; m++)
    sum += N(n-1, k-m);
}
```

т.е. вынос if-ов из цикла дает процентов 10

Первоначальный вариант

```
real        0m4.593s
user        0m4.100s
sys         0m0.112s
```

Оптимизированый

```
real        0m4.166s
user        0m3.676s
sys         0m0.084s
```

C gcc -O3

первоначальный

```
real        0m3.659s
user        0m3.148s
sys         0m0.104s
```

оптимизированный

```
real        0m2.836s
user        0m2.504s
sys         0m0.080s
```