# Ускоренне процесса

Tags: c++, алгоритм

**Условие задачи:**
You have some set of tickets. First ticket is numbered M, last – N.
M and N have the following limitations: 10000000 ≤ M < N ≤ 99999999.
Your task is to identify total number of "lucky" tickets in the given range.
We say that ticket is "lucky", if the sum of first 4 digits equals to the sum of last 4 digits.

(прим. правки) **Перевод:**

> Вы имеется некоторое множество билетов. Первый билет имеет номер M, последний - N.
>   M и N находятся в пределах: 10000000 ≤ M < N ≤ 99999999.
>   Ваша задача: найти количество счастливых билетов в заданном диапазоне.
>   Счастливым называется тот билет, сумма первых 4 цифр которого равна сумме последних 4 цифр.

**Input:**
Contains first and the last possible number of the tickets.

> На входе вы имеете первый и последний номер билета(диапазон).

**Output:**
Total number of "lucky" tickets in given range.

> Вывести общее количество счастливых билетов в заданном диапазоне.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int lucky(int *a, int *b)
{
    int count = 0, temp, i, res1 = 0, res2 = 0;
    int var1 = *a;
    for (i = 0;i < 4;i++)
    {
        temp = var1 % 10;
        var1 /= 10;
        res1 += temp;
    }
    for (i = 0;i < 4;i++)
    {
        temp = var1 % 10;
        var1 /= 10;
        res2 += temp;
    }
    if (res1 == res2)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}   
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int *aP, *bP;
    aP = &a;
    bP = &b;
    int count2=0,count3=0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for(int i = a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        if(lucky(&a,&b)>count2)
        {
            count3++;
        }
        a++;
    }
    cout << count3 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Хотелось бы уменьшить время выполнения с 8 секунд хотя бы до 3, при входных данных `10000000` и `99999999`.

Comment: плохая идея делать цикл на 100 миллионов элементов...

Comment: Этот вопрос очень подробно уже обсуждался здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197903

Answer (score 1):

В цикле увеличивающим число 1 за раз сумма цифр старших четырех разрядов меняется один раз на 10000 циклов и происходит это когда младшие 4 разряда равны 0.

Нет никакой необходимости раскладывать число каждый раз на 4 разряда, ибо это 4 операции деления. Можно сделать небольшой массив с суммами цифр двух разрядов (если памяти много можно и для всех 4х разрядов заранее посчитать суммы).

Исходя из этого готовим заранее массив сумм для чисел от 0 до 99 и используем его для вычисления полной суммы 4х разрядов, разбивая пополам по 2 разряда. Сумму для старшей части числа вычисляем только в случае, когда она изменилась.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int count3=0;
    a = 10000000;
    b = 99999999;
    char sum[100];
    for(int i=0;i<=99;i++) sum[i]=i/10+i%10;
    //cin >> a >> b;
    int h=0,h_sum;
    for(int i = a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        int l=i%10000;
        if(l==0 || h==0) {
         h=i/10000;
         h_sum=*(sum+h/100)+*(sum+h%100);
        }
        count3+= (sum[l/100]+sum[l%100] == h_sum);
    }
    cout << count3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Для демонстрации работы "с указателями" я в одном месте заменил квадратные скобки при обращении к sum на вычисление по указателю. Дальнейшее приведение к "учебному" виду, оставляю вам. Вариантов масса: готовить массив sum отдельной функцией, вынести расчет суммы разрядов в отдельную функцию и передавать ей помимо числа еще и указатель на этот массив. Кроме того функции надо где то хранить предыдущее вычисленное значение h_sum, его так же можно передавать по указателю...

Answer (score 0):

Скажем так, здесь есть 2 варианта ускорения - переписать всё с 0 и правильным алгоритмом на основе динамики по числу. И 2 - просто написать то что есть **нормально** Зачем куча указателей, зачем странные проверки... Например этот код имеет шансы отработать за 3 секунды. На крайняк можно развернуть циклы.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int count3=0;
    a = 10000000;
    b = 99999999;
    //cin >> a >> b;
    for(int i = a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        int ii = i;
        int z = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int q = 0; q < 4; q++,ii/=10)
            z+=ii%10;
        for (int q = 0; q < 4; q++,ii/=10)
            x+=ii%10;       
        count3+= (z == x);
    }
    cout << count3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, просто в задании просят использовать указатели. http://contester.iitu.kz:9006/ru/problem-pid-c46e?ps=1&smt=a&smpwid=0 (русская версия сайта)

Comment: @KairatAmanzharov они здесь не нужны, только замедляют работу.

Comment: У нас тема Указатели, и во всех заданиях просят их использовать, а также надо в функции все написать

Comment: ну тогда сами думайте, как-то некультурно с действующего соревнования задания делать всем