# Подсчитайте количество счастливых билетов, у которых сумма первых трёх цифр равна N

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

***Вопрос: как упростить проверку цикла в цикле?***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n,count =0;
    cin >> n;

    for(int q=0;q<10;q++){
        for(int w=0;w<10;w++){
            for(int e=0;e<10;e++){
                for(int r=0;r<10;r++){
                    for(int t=0;t<10;t++){
                        for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
                            if ((q+w+e == r+t+y) && (q+w+e == n)) count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Подсчитайте количество счастливых билетов, у которых сумма первых трёх
>   цифр равна `N`.
>
> Счастливым билетом называется билет с шестизначным номером, у которого
>   сумма первых трёх цифр равна сумме трёх последних.

Comment: Алгоритм жутко неоптимален. Грамотный подход уже рассматривался в [этом вопросе здесь же](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197903/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто перебором -

```
int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        int s = i%10 + (i/10)%10 + (i/100)%10;
        if(s == N && s == (i/1000)%10 + (i/10000)%10 +(i/100000)%10)
            count++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: У меня ещё есть вопрос: что делать, если например много вложенных циклов? Или например: есть массив чисел, найти три (вроде найбольших) числа с которых можно сделать треугольник..

Comment: Какой-то общий совет дать трудно. Пожалуй, надо смотреть в каждом конкретном случае...

Comment: @Harry, см. комментарий к ответу. Алгоритм поиска СБ здесь уже обсуждался. Решение VladD пока в лидерах :)

Comment: @PinkTux Этот вопрос еще в 70-х годах обсуждался в "Кванте" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int q=0;q<10;q++){
    for(int w=0;w<10;w++){
        for(int e=0;e<10;e++){
            if (q+w+e == n)
                count++;
        }
    }
}

count = count * count;
```

Или, используя решение @Harry:

```
for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int s = i%10 + (i/10)%10 + (i/100)%10;
    if (s == n)
        count++;
}

count = count * count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно упростить алгоритм.

[6 вложенных циклов](http://ideone.com/PChS3k) не нужны.
Как уже [сказал](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592366/178988) @Igor, достаточно трёх.

Но на самом деле и третий цикл лишний - если мы знаем первые 2 цифры, то третью можно однозначно получить вычитанием суммы двух имеющихся из n. Остаётся только проверить, что получивщееся число действительно годится на роль цифры:

http://ideone.com/PChS3k

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, res = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for(int q=0; q<10; q++)
        for(int w=0; w<10; w++)
        {
            int t = n - q - w;
            res += t >= 0 && t <= 9;
        }

    cout << res * res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Если рассматривать все X комбинаций трёх цифр суммой N как символы алфавита, то число возможных билетов это число возможных слов из двух символов. Это X<sup>2</sup>.
- Суммируя три числа 0-9 можно получить не так уж много значений, всего лишь от 0 до 27. Другого ввода нет. Можно посчитать для каждого значения N число X заранее.

  - Да даже результаты можно посчитать заранее!
  - Вопрос в том, как из N получить X.

---

На самом деле, задача нехитрая.

Прикинем, что если в блоке из трёх цифр *ABC* зафиксировать цифру на месте *А*, то любое значение *В* однозначно определяет *С* (если сочетания с такими значениями вообще существуют). Причём *B + C = N - A*.

Сколько комбинаций существует для В и С, если А зафиксировано?

- Если *N - A* меньше нуля или больше 18 -- то ни одной. Это ограничивает диапазон перебора для *А*.
- Если *N - A* в диапазоне от 0 до 18, то можно поперебирать комбинации в голове и сразу бросается в глаза закономерность:

  - *N - A = 0* => 1 вариант (00)
  - *N - A = 1* => 2 варианта (10, 01)
  - *N - A = 2* => 3 варианта (20, 11, 02)
  - *N - A = 3* => 4 варианта (30, 21, 12, 03)
  - ...
  - *N - A = 9* => 10 вариантов (90, 81, 72, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 18, 09)
  - ...
  - *N - A = 18* => 1 вариант (99)

  Видите закономерность? Почему она имеет место, можете на досуге подумать, а я расскажу, как это использовать.

  Если построить график числа вариантов от *N - A*, будет видно, что это можно реализовать через функцию модуля со сдвигом и отражением по вертикали: `- abs(N - A - 9) + 10` (отразить `abs(N - A)` по вертикали, сдвинуть на 9 вправо и на 10 вверх)

  Таким образом, нужно перебрать значения *A* от 0 до 9, и для значений *N - A* между 0 и 18 просуммировать значения вышеуказанного выражения. Получится X.

Написать программным кодом предлагаю самостоятельно `:)`