# Пять Чисел Задача C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Написал такой код, проходит половину тестов, из тех что не проходят - половина ограничение по времени, половина неверный ответ.
Где в коде ошибка и как её исправить?
Задача:
[image: Задача]

Код :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int nextPrime(int n) {
    n++;
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return nextPrime(n);
    return n;
}
bool isExpOf2(long int x) {
    return ((x != 0) && ((x & (~x + 1)) == x));
}
int main() {

    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");

    long int k = 0, p = 0, a[5], tempx100;
    double temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        inp >> a[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        p = nextPrime(1);
    k:
        temp = a[i];
        temp /= p;
        tempx100 = temp * 100;
        if (p > a[i]) {
            otp << "NO" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (tempx100 % 100 == 0) {
            if (isExpOf2((int)temp)) {
                otp << "YES" << endl;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                p = nextPrime(p);
                goto k;
            }
        }
        else {
            p = nextPrime(p);
            goto k;
        }

    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Ответ вы уже получили, но на будущее - задания нужно переводить на русский.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat переводил 1 раз когда видел, сейчас не заметил, извините.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то у вас наверчено такого, что разобраться, что вы делаете, не получается...

```
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i+=2)
        if (n%i==0) return false;
    return true;
}


bool format(int n)
{
    while(n%2==0) n/=2;
    return isPrime(n);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ifstream inp("input.txt");
    ofstream otp("output.txt");
    for(int n, i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        inp >> n;
        otp << (format(n) ? "YES\n" : "NO\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код провалил 3 теста из 10. 1 из-за времени, 2 неверный ответ.

Comment: Дайте точный URL, тогда повожусь. Я свой код даже не компилировал, показал только, куда копать :)

Comment: Я могу ссылку дать, но это закрытый ресурс, без логина и пароля зайти у вас не получится.

Comment: Ну тогда извините... Если негде провериться - то и возиться как-то не хочется...

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет логина и пароля =(
Но я могу проверять ваш код.

Comment: Замените -ка все `int` на `long long int` и посмотрите. На ну очень большом числе цикл может зацикливаться...

Comment: Из условия неясно, должно ли p отличаться от 2 - это я к тому, что 2^n вернёт true

Comment: Заменил на long long int, 2 теста провалены - неверный ответ. Тест который был с ошибкой по времени пройден.

Comment: @MBo Гм, и в самом деле :) Но тогда это же число имеет вид 2^n*1, а 1 не простое :)

Comment: А знаете, @MBo может быть и прав... Попробуйте первой строкой в `isPrime` дописать `if (n==1) return true;` :)

Comment: 2^(n-1)*2 формально подходит по условию, но как они это интерпретируют?

Comment: Так оно сейчас и возвращает true

Comment: Ничего не поменялось

Comment: а `if (n==1) return false;` ?

Comment: @MBo 3 из 10 тестов только прошло

Comment: Что-то не пойму тогда... Разве что у них опечатка и k должно быть строго больше нуля... Попробуйте в `format` первой строкой поставить `if (n%2) return false;`

Comment: @Harry все тесты кроме 1 завалены.

Comment: Все, пас... надоело :) Как найдете ошибку - скажите :)

Comment: @Harry Отпишу когда найду.

Comment: @Harry посидел немного над кодом, не понимаю в чем ошибка. Интересный факт - не проходят тесты 5 и 10, это те же тесты что не проходили с моим кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Понятия не имею почему ваша задача неверна, может изза проверки на простоту до корня.
Приведу свою идею.

Мне кажется у вас похожая была :) А идея такова:с помощью решета Эратосфена ищем наименьшее число p такое что A[i] / p = 2 ^ k.

Ну эту проверку можно сделать с помощью функции двоичного логарифма. Ну и вроде все.

Краткая реализация на python:

```
from math import log2
a = list(map(int,input().split()))
MAX = 100 # Выберете число под лимит задачи :)
prime = MAX*[1]
#если число 1 - не простое,то дописать: prime[1] = 0
arr = []
#Решето Эратосфена
for i in range(2,MAX):
    if prime[i]:        
        j = i*i
        arr.append(i)
        while j < MAX:
            prime[j] = 0
            j+=i
for i in range(0,5):
    q = 0
    for j in range(0,len(arr)):
        if log2(a[i]/arr[j])==int(log2(a[i]/arr[j])):
            q = 1
            break
    if q==0:print("NO")
    else:print("YES")
```